# OpenAI API not reading api key in my .env.local file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, openai-api

I am trying to build a react app (using latest Next.js and running it locally, no backend) that uses the OpenAI API and am running into an issue with the API Key. Currently, if I keep the api key in my `.env.local` file and reference it when creating a new configuration, I get a 401 error. If I add the API key directly in the configuration (definitely would not push my code this way), everything works. I'm not using a server backend. I'm using Google Firebase as the backend. Any reason why this would be happening?

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

const configuration = new Configuration({
     // apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
     apiKey: 'sk-KEY_REMOVED'
})

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration)

export default openai;
```

In my `.env.local` file, i have tried simply putting api key as:

1. `OPENAI_API_KEY=Key`
2. `OPENAI_API_KEY='Key'`
3. `OPENAI_API_KEY="Key"`

Comment: You need to post how this is being served.

Comment: By default, environment variables are only available on the server. Please post more information for further knowledge.